How to check if object property is optional (strict mode agnostic)?
This question is similar to:
Check if an object property is optional
However the answer given there relies on undefined extends which is not reliable (the behavior changes if strict mode is enabled vs. disabled).
For example:
type x = {
    a?: string
    b: number
}

type aOptional = undefined extends x["a"] ? true : false // true strict mode on, true strict mode off
type bOptional = undefined extends x["b"] ? true : false // false strict mode on, true strict mode off

This is problematic since strict mode is off by default, which means this will be broken by default.
Assuming it is possible, how can I achieve the same thing in a strict mode agnostic way?
(we can close this question and update the other if it's possible)

undefined extends is wrong even with strict mode on, because you can have type X = {a?: string, b: number | undefined} and have both show up as "optional". The "right" test is whether {} extends Pick<T, K> as shown in this playground link and it should work whether or not you're using --strict (but you really should use --strict or else so many other things will be weird).

the other question seems to regard "optional" as "accepts null" (even though that's not conventional terminology for TypeScript).  If you turn off strict mode then everything accepts null and undefined. So presumably the question only makes sense with strict mode on.
